# Can SQL 2008 R2 and a SQL express installation coexist on same machine without problems?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-web-developer

I have SQL 2008 R2 on my computer and it works fine with the database. If I install Visual Web Developer 2010 express it says I have to install SQL Express , per it is a dependency. I would prefer to only install web developer.

Will an express installation effect my current installation's operation at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can coexist as they will be installed as separate services - see this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f71e89a0-ef12-4029-8119-a466c9a40ff6)

Comment: Thanks Richard for the quick response. I couldn't find an exact answer when googling. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Officially, they can coexist.

Unofficially, my experience with a joint installation is painful.  SQL Server patches would fail mysteriously on machines with a joint install.  Sometimes you could find fix information in a KB article, sometimes not.  Sometimes reinstalling SQL Server worked, sometimes an OS reinstall was required.

You can take the risk on a development server, but I wouldn't do this in production.